# DateTimeField throwing datetime is not serializeable

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have added a new Datetime field in my model.

```
class MyModel:
    valid_upto = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

and my serializer code is

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

When i am updating one instance i am getting `TypeError: Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable`
the value that can come in valid_upto is `None` or a datetime value which i am getting from `timezone.now()`

Answer (score 0):

probably you are wrong with field attribute. More here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now

```
class MyModel:
    valid_upto = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

By default this field is `not editable`. And `serializer` should check it.
But if you want, you remove this field manually:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ('valid_upto', )
```